# Firebird ado.net dynamic sql: multiple select statements possible?

Tags: sql, select, ado.net, firebird

I'm refactoring a c# application and optimizing some queries.  The app supports Microsoft SQL server and Firebird.

I can't seem to find any information regarding issuing multiple select statements in Dynamic SQL on Firebird.

For example this is valid for Microsoft SQL server:
"SELECT * FROM ATABLE; SELECT * FROM ANOTHERTABLE;"

However Firebird calls invalid token on the semicolon.

Note this is called from c# code using the ADO.NET Firebird driver.

Comment: Dynamic SQL can leave you open to injection attacks. Sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird does not support multipel select within the same command

Comment: I thought so but I wanted to be sure.  Thank you Thomas